# Есть ли замена WebEngine?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть ли какая нибудь замена WebEngine? Потому что в моем приложении есть подозрение, что он является причиной утечки оперативки и хотелось бы заменить его чем нибудь чтобы проверить это.

Comment: У вас есть подозрение или вы в этом точно уверены? Альтернатив не находил, т.к. все устраивало.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, сейчас проверил на простом примере и точно уверен. если, как пример, пустить его в бесконечном цикле с загрузкой 1 страницы, то он будет постепенно съедать оперативку. я не знаю может он кэш хранит или еще что то и как его очистить вообще без понятия

Comment: @mckay Оказывается это проcто баг в javaFX, вот аналогичных вопросов куча:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266013/exploding-memory-usage-in-javafx-webview-while-loading-many-pages

Баг описан на странице oracle 
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8159594

Будет исправлен в jdk9
думаю стоит попрбовать 
https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok спасибо

Comment: @mckay всегда рад помочь, отпишитесь пожалуйста как будет результат

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok, с jdk9 отличные показатели. 1.2gb после часа работы, что на много меньше чем с jdk8. Пришлось еще установить новый intellij idea версии 2017.1, предыдущая версия не захотела с новым jdk работать. Все бы хорошо только приложение стало иногда падать с фатальной ошибкой (jfxwebkit.dll причина падения). Наверно сыроват пока jdk9

Comment: @mckay было бы неплохо увидеть stack trace, может есть решение